# What goes into the acoustic profile of nightclubs?

Tags: acoustics

I am working on a term paper for a physics class and I am studying the acoustics of nightclubs. The only issues I've run into is I found it difficult to find many sources on the types of materials and sizes of nightclubs. I also found it difficult to find research on how speakers are arranged in nightclubs. I was wondering if anyone could point me to any sources or help explain how nightclubs are acoustically treated.

Any help from physicists or people with experience in the sound industry would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will be a tough task.

I have played countless gigs in nightclubs over the last 50 years or so, and in most of those cases I was also responsible for running the band sound system from on stage during the performance. In 99% of those cases the nightclubs had no acoustic treatment at all, and no built-in sound system either.

This means that most of the night clubs in existence cannot furnish you with useful data. Only a minority of them have *house PA systems* and only the poshest ones will have any sort of acoustic treatment in their performance space.

I would suggest that you call around to the clubs in your area and find out which ones have a house PA and then ask for a meeting with the *sound man* responsible for running it, and note the specs for the system and any acoustic treatment installed.